# I am using Sun OS, I want my script to read date from a file(in format %Y%m%d) and add 1 day to that date

Tags: date, unix, ksh, sunos

I am working in Sun OS environment, I want to add a functionality to my existing unix ksh script where it allows to read a date(in %Y%m%d format) from a file and add 1 day and rewrite the same into that file. [please note: not adding day to current date instead i want to add 1 day to i/p date present in a file].
Eg:DateFile.dat
20200620
I want my script to change it to 20200621 at the end of run.
My code as below:

```
#!/bin/ksh
ip_dte</home/{file_Path}
echo $ip_dte
dte_add=`TZ=AEST-24 "$ip_dte"`
echo $dte_add
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like that ? :

```
#!/bin/ksh

# Starting date, YYYYMMDD (yes I should verify the format :) )
FIRST_DATE=$1
[[ -z $FIRST_DATE ]] && FIRST_DATE=$(date +"%Y%m%d")

# 1 day in seconds
PERIOD=86400

# Transform the starting date in second and add 1 day
SECOND_DATE=$(( $(date -d "$FIRST_DATE" +"%s")+$PERIOD ))

# Transform the second date from second to human date format
print "Second date is $(date -d @"$SECOND_DATE" +"%Y%m%d")"
```

Comment: This commands not working in sun solaris and i am getting error "date: illegal option -- d" and Usage: date [-u], date [-u] +format, date -a etc..

Answer (score 0):

We can let `date` do the calculations and formatting for us:

```
$ date1='20200415'

$ date -d "${date1}+1 day"                     # add 1 day, use default output format
Thu Apr 16 00:00:00 UTC 2020

$date -d "${date1}+1 day" '+%Y%m%d'            # add 1 day, change to YYYYMMDD format
20200416

$ date2=$(date -d "${date1}+1 day" '+%Y%m%d')  # save new date in variable in YYYYMMDD format
$ echo "${date2}"
20200416
```

Here's a [ksh fiddle](http://tpcg.io/twCPuzrp) of the above.

Comment: Hi mark, Thanks for the response. I think this will work in linux but not with sun solaris.

Comment: what's your `ksh` version (`ksh --version`)?  did you try it in solaris and if so what error/message did you receive?

Comment: ksh version: M-11/16/88i and error I am getting: "date: illegal option -- d" and Usage: date [-u], date [-u] +format, date -a etc..

Answer (score 0):

The other answers will work if you have `‎CSWcoreutils` or `SUNWgnu-coreutils` installed. You may have to run `gdate` or `/usr/gnu/bin/date`.

But if you have a recent version of Solaris, ksh will be ksh93, and you can use the `%T` format in printf:

```
$ cat ddd
20200620
$ ip_dte=`cat ddd`
$ printf "%(%Y%m%d)T\n" "$ip_dte tomorrow"
20200621
```

Comment: Hi Mark, Thanks for the response. My solaris version is 5.10 and ksh version: M-11/16/88i

Comment: OK. You might have coreutils on the **Solaris 10 Companion CD**, which came in the Solaris 10 CD collection packet. I think it installs packages to `/usr/sfw/bin`. Keep in mind that software this old may have security bugs.

Answer (score 0):

If you have perl with the Time::Local module on the old Solaris server, try this:

```
#!/bin/ksh
ip_dte=20200531 # or read date from file into ip_dte
echo $ip_dte
timestamp=`perl -MTime::Local=timelocal -e '($y,$m,$d) = $ARGV[0] =~ /(\d\d\d\d)(\d\d)(\d\d)/; $m=$m-1; print timelocal(1,1,1,$d,$m,$y);' $ip_dte`
dte_add=`perl -MPOSIX=strftime -e 'print strftime("%Y%m%d", localtime($ARGV[0] +86400));' $timestamp`
echo $dte_add
```

Comment: Hi, Thanks for your valuable reply.Sorry i was not active due to health issues. I checked the above code and it is working perfect in my sun OS  system.

Comment: I have another requirement here. Same as adding date, i need to add user given time(in hour) to sysdate time taken from SQL. Eg: my sysdate time from sql is 10/08/2020 12:29:29 PM and user pass 3 as i/p, it should add 3 hours to the sysdate time and print the o/p. Thanks in advance